# Proper Disposing HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#

I would like to send many requests to web using this method

```
void MyMethod()
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[0].InvokeRequired)
    {
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest0_1 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
        httpWebRequest0_1.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        httpWebRequest0_1.KeepAlive = true;
        httpWebRequest0_1.Proxy = (IWebProxy)webProxy;
        string output = this.Smethod0(httpWebRequest0_1);
    }
    else
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyMethod))
        {
            IsBackground = true
        }.Start();
    }
}

public string Smethod0(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest0)
{
    return new StreamReader(this.smethod_1(httpWebRequest0).GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true).ReadToEnd();
}

public HttpWebResponse smethod_1(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest_0)
{
    HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse;
    try
    {
        httpWebRequest_0.Method = "GET";
        httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest_0.GetResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ProjectData.SetProjectError(ex);
        httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)null;
        ProjectData.ClearProjectError();
    }
    return httpWebResponse;
}
```

I want to send many requests to my Url using timer with interval 150 miliseconds

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MyMethod();
}
```

I know it is fast and this can cause unmanaged memory.

[image: Graph 1]

I guess because I'm sending many requests that haven't been finished.
Of course i change

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 1000;
```

My goal is to send many requests at once and then somehow dispose all of them and that should repeat the graph show look something like that

[image: Graph 2]

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: How do you know that your `HttpWebRequest` objects are leaking? Huge unmanaged memory can be also a sign for the wrong usage of `VirtualAllocation` by an unmanaged code. [VMMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/vmmap) can help you to see that this memory space is *unusable* or is part of the *private working set*.

Comment: how can i fix it

Comment: Before we jump onto the solution part, we have to be sure that what is causing the growth of the unmanaged memory. Please measure once then measure twice, derive a conclusion and just after that think about solutions that can solve the issue.

Comment: You could dispose the `StreamReader` you create in `Smethod0`, this in turn will dispose the response stream.